# Customize Community Tabs

Tags: tab, community, developer-edition

Referring to the Salesforce page: 
[https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_service_cloud.meta/workbook_service_cloud/service3_step5.htm](http://page).

*Setup* - *Customize* - *Communities* - *All Communities*

1. Instead of *Edit* there is *Manage*.
2. I should click on:

   ```
    Click Tabs & Pages
   ```

   but I cannot find it on my page.

Considering that I have a Developer Edition, do you know what could be the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That workbook is out of date for changes they made for unified community setup and reporting. Click Manage next to the community you want to make the changes for, then Administration>Tabs.